# Laravel Telescope does not record requests coming from TestCase

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

For debugging purpose, I would like to have Telescope record any requests coming from Testing suite. Telescope does not at the moment and I have no ideas why.

I enabled telescope in `phpunit.xml`

```
<env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="true"/>
```

This is my Feature Test

```
$this->getJson('/api/vehicle')->assertStatus(401);
```

When I opened the Telescope, there is no entry for `/api/vehicle` saved.

Comment: https://dyrynda.com.au/blog/using-laravel-telescope-in-specific-environments maybe this is what you looking for ?

Comment: the link tells me how to not include Telescope in build and testing env. By default, Telescope should work in any environment and it is where I stand at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I need to always force Telescope to record in TelescopeServiceProvider

```
class TelescopeServiceProvider extends TelescopeApplicationServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // Telescope::night();

        Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) {
            if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
                return true;
            }

            if ($this->app->environment('testing')) {
                return true;
            }

            return $entry->isReportableException() ||
                   $entry->isFailedJob() ||
                   $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
                   $entry->hasMonitoredTag();
        });
    }
```

And since the telescope frontend is linked to `development-database`, the telescope entries recorded during `testing` are saved in `testing-database`, that explain when I refresh the Telescope front-end (which use `development-database`), nothing was shown.

Comment: are you in production ?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/347#issuecomment-442937226 maybe this helps ?